# Detecting click on/outside of an image doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I want to detect whether or not a click has happened on an image:

```
var myImg = document.getElementById("my_img123");

//here I have some stuff that uses myImg



document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  if (evt.currentTarget === myImg) {
    alert("click on image");
  } else {
    alert("click outside of image");
  }
});
```

**No matter where** I click, it always shows "click outside of image"

Why? Fix?

Comment: For starters that conditional is backwards. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue

Comment: @charlietfl read more carefully

Comment: I read carefully and saw there isn't any html for us to test your problem and also can see you edited the conditional after my remark

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.target` instead of `event.currentTarget`.

The `currentTarget` will always be the `document` since that is where the listener is attached.

The `target` is the inner most element event occurs on

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("div");

document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  if (evt.target === myDiv) {
    console.log("click on div");
  } else {
    console.log("click outside of div");
  }
});
```

```html
<br/>
<button>Test</button>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="div">Div instead of image<br/> More div content<br/></div>
<br/>
<button>Another button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
   if (evt.currentTarget !== myImg) {
       alert("click on image");
   } else {
       alert("click outside of image");
   }
});
```

Try:

```
myImg.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
     alert("click on image");
});
```

EDIT: This assumes that you only need to detect the image click. If you have to detect a non image click as well then this solution won't work.